# XML сериализация вложенного DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Возникла проблема, решение которой пока не могу найти. 
Варианты "сохранять через DataTable.writexml" - **не предлагать**.

---

Суть проблемы такова:
существует класс содержащий в себе параметр

```
    internal class ClassPositions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// содержание класса позиций
        /// </summary>
        private ClassTypeData.PositionsData positions = new ClassTypeData.PositionsData();
}
```

класс параметра содержит в себе DataTable:

```
public class ClassTypeData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// список позиций для справочника
    /// </summary>
    public class PositionsData {
        /// <summary>
        /// версия справочника позиций
        /// </summary>
        public string version = "1.0.0.1";
        /// <summary>
        /// файл для сохранения/загрузки позиций справочника
        /// </summary>
        public string file = "positions.xml";
        /// <summary>
        /// таблица с позициями для смет
        /// </summary>
        public DataTable table_positions = new DataTable("positions");
    }
}
```

В отдельном где-то написанном методе выполняем сериализацию этого параметра. В моем случае конечно же тип obj = class PositionsData

```
    public static void save_to_file(object obj, string filename = null)
    {
        if (filename.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
                xml.Serialize(file, obj);
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема возникает в том, что DataTable например содержит 3 строчки данных, но при такой сериализации в XML сохраняется только 2 строки (1 строка почему-то теряется и в XML файл не попадает), вместо трех.
Если выполнить DataTable.WriteXml, то сохранятся все 3 строчки, но мне этот вариант не интересен.

---

**Внимание вопрос**: как сделать мой подход к сериализации класса с вложенным DataTable таким образом, чтобы содержание строк DataTable сохранялось полноценно без потери 1 строки ?

Comment: Может вместо `DataTable` использовать `List<>` ?

Comment: @nick_n_a, первый вариант программы писал работая с List и даже Dictionary с собственной сериализацией его. В итоге пришел к решению что работа с DataTable проще всего, как некая аналогия БД только в ОЗУ. Аналогия с БД в том, что можно иметь много полей и много строк. С вариантом List придется делать вложенности или же отсутствие колок и дополнительные методы для визуального отображения в виде таблиц.

Comment: @nick_n_a, тем более сам компонент DataTable обладает необходимым интерфейсом сериализации, возможно проблема в том, что я что-то упускаю (какой-то аттрибут и т.п.), а возможно баг у Microsoft.

Comment: Покажите больше кода: какие манипуляции вы выполняете с этим `DataTable`. Как данные добавляются/удаляются. Скорей всего, строка добавлена/изменена/удалена, но не помечена соответствующим образом. Вызовите метод `AcceptChanges()` у вашего `DataTable` перед сериализацией.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо за наводку мыслей. Черкнете свой коммент в виде ответа, чтобы я его отметил "как ответ" для вопроса ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки в `DataTable` могут быть в разных состояниях [`DataRowState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx). Чтобы эти изменения были приняты и, соответственно, были записаны при сериализации, необходимо вызвать метод [`AcceptChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) (или `RejectChanges()`, если нужно отказаться от изменений).

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на мысли. Привык работать с БД напрямую, забыл что такое визуальные компоненты при редактировании данных.  У меня связка DataGridView + BindingSource+DataTable, но ваш ответ вполне нормальный и верный, везде сохранить и применить изменения.
Проблема была в том, что DataGridView пока не кликнешь на другой строке, ту что редактировал не сохранялась, даже если нажать Enter. Все стало сохранять сделав как вы посоветовали, везде указав "завершить редактирование"/"применить изменения".